# Install Tensorflow-GPU with conda for GTX 1050 on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, user-guide

I am new to tensorflow and wanted some help installing it.

I have Miniconda3 with python 3.7.7.

I have **8GB RAM, i7-7700hq core and GTX-1050**, 4GB RAM graphics card with **Cuda driver version 9.2.209** version (I saw this from Nvidia control panel in NVCUDA.DLL)

I have tried to follow instructions on medium, youtube but to no use.

Can someone please help me setup tensorflow-gpu(preferably 2.1.0 but I'll be happy with any version as long as it is working) on my laptop?

Please feel free to ask any questions/information that you might need to answer.

Thank you :)

Comment: You should update your question with the specific error you are trying to resolve. You haven't given us enough information to help you. To install tensorflow GPU it's just `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. After you do that, what goes wrong for you?

Comment: @DavidParks RuntimeError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
cudatoolkit version in conda- 10.2

Comment: @DavidParks Command was tf.test.is_gpu_available()

Comment: You can edit the question directly, better than adding lots of comments. Have you been through this discussion on the issue? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21832

Comment: @DavidParks I found the issue. My Nvida driver was not upto date. Had to go through docs checking which 'latest; driver supports CUDA 10.1

Comment: Nice, you should write up the solution as an answer to your own question so others benefit from the knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version Checks**-

- Check which GPU you are using (win+X) -> Device Manager -> Display Adapters
- Determine which version of Tensorflow you want to use.
- Determine CUDA version supported by tensorflow version [from here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). 2.1.0 supports 10.1

**Prerequisites**-

- CUDA enabled GPU ([check here to check](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus))
- Visual Studio. This is required to install GCC compiler. You can also go with Windows SDK but I have not tried that.

**Steps**-

1. Download CUDA toolkit for the required version [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)
2. Download latest cuDNN for your cuda version [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) (You have to register with Nvidia for this).
3. Install CUDA toolkit. It will automatically install the required Nvidia driver too.
4. Install cuDNN using these [instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#install-windows)

**Edit** - 
You need to ensure your graphics card has the necessary drivers to support CUDA version required by tensorflow. I had to go through docs of each driver to to this. ([Check drivers for your GPU](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx))